# Deploy same eclipse project with different property files to 2 different apache tomcats

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, deployment

I have 2 tomcats in Eclipse and I want to deploy same project on those two tomcats with different property files is that possible?

Thanks,
Mika

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this issue is to make all properties files external and reference them from application.

Comment: in other words not possible :}

Comment: Are you deploying directly from eclipse? Are you using Maven, Ant or anything else?